# Как сделать pop-up в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

В игровой сцене есть менюшка с клавишами (*GameObject → UI → Button*).
Я хочу, что бы при нажатии на клавишу "*About*" появлялся pop-up (всплывающее окно) с информацией о игре.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов много. Старайтесь выделять в вопросе главную проблему.

Если просто нет идей как делаются такие окошки, то пример.
Если вы используете Canvas, то можно, сделать прозрачную Panel на весь Canvas, а на нее положить нужные вам для всплывающего окна компоненты. Например картинку фона окна, Title окна текстовый, кнопку для закрытия окна и сам текст сообщения. Сохраните эту панель в префаб и используйте, когда нужно.

Только учтите, что такая панель должна лежать выше остального UI, чтобы блокировать все клики. Прикольнее, когда панель не полностью прозрачная, а имеет затемнение (так пользователям видно, что остальной UI заблокирован).

Не забудьте настроить правильно растягивание, чтобы текст и само окошко адекватно смотрелось на разных экранах, но затемнение было на весь экран. Можно просто центрировать без растягивания окошко, а панель растягивать на весь экран.

Comment: Спасибо, я просто де/активирую объект. Но это не то, я думал можно сделать что бы появлялось новое окошно как в компютерных OS.

Сейчас хочу разобраться, как сделать что бы объект выезжал при активации и уезжал назад при деактивации.

Comment: Чтобы был элемент окна, нужно его или сделать самому или использовать чье-то готовое решение. Некоторые UI библиотеки сторонние должны предоставлять компоненты окон. А для выезжания и прочих фишек можно использовать анимацию. Например, поставляемую в самой Unity3d.